# About ubuntu-restricted-extras on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, codecs, ubuntu-restricted-extras

Oxideqt-codecs: Wanting to install ubuntu-restricted-extras package from the Software Center I get a warning that says to install that package must uninstall this other appears. Then in a terminal I ran this command: apt-get remove oxideqt-codecs. Oxideqt-codecs-extra: When you call this a new package is installed. Then I went to try to install ubuntu-restricted-extras again from the Software Center and this time if installed without noticing anything.

I want to ask:

1. Are there negative consequences to uninstall the package oxideqt-codecs to install ubuntu-restricted-extras?

Two. Why this happens in Ubuntu 14.04 and not Ubuntu 12.04?

<sup>[Originally in Spanish, translated through Google translate.](https://askubuntu.com/posts/473602/revisions)</sup>

Comment: English only please. You got the title in English, why not the body? Anyway, can you try to install ubuntu-restricted-extras from the terminal and paste the entire output into your question? ([edit] it to add this) Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

[`oxideqt-codecs-extra`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/oxideqt-codecs-extra) would of been installed as it is recomended by [`ubuntu-restricted-addons`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/ubuntu-restricted-addons), which in turn is depended on by [`ubuntu-restricted-extras`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/ubuntu-restricted-extras).

For more details on `oxideqt-codecs-extra`, you can run `apt-cache show oxideqt-codecs-extra`. This gives the following with English set as the locale:

```
...
Replaces: liboxideqtcore0 (<< 1.0.0~bzr488), oxideqt-codecs
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.7), libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1)
Conflicts: oxideqt-codecs
Breaks: liboxideqtcore0 (<< 1.0.0~bzr488)
Filename: pool/main/o/oxide-qt/oxideqt-codecs-extra_1.0.0~bzr501-0ubuntu2_i386.deb
...
Description-en: Web browser engine library for Qt (codecs)
 Oxide is a web browser engine library based on Google Chromium, that makes
 it easy to embed web content in your Qt application
 .
 This package provides some media codecs needed for the HTML5 <audio> and
 <video> tags. Included are the Theora, Vorbis, Opus, VP8, VP9, MP3, AAC
 and H.264 codecs
...
```

The important bit is `Conflicts: oxideqt-codecs` - when it is checked before it it installed, all packages that conflicted with it are removed. So the `oxideqt-codecs` package would be removed before the`oxideqt-codecs-extra` package is installed so they do not conflict.

The `oxideqt-codecs-*` packages provide extra codecs for [HTML5 `<video>` and `<audio>`](http://html5media.info/) rendering by the Oxide engine. This can be used by QT applications - which you likely do not need as most major browsers include these plugins or will those provided by `gstreamer0.10-plugins*` and other packages.

1) The `oxideqt-codecs-extra` likely includes what is included in `oxideqt-codecs`, so there is no need for the `oxideqt-codecs` package - which is also why the packages conflict. So having only the `oxideqt-codecs-extra` package should be fine.

2) Looking [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=oxideqt-codecs) and [here](https://launchpad.net/oxide), this package has only been available since this version of Ubuntu (Trusty 14.04), so it has not been included in previous releases like 12.04 to cause any problems.

Reference: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2217426